# Array or string in input data (lodash)

Tags: lodash

I have String or Array of names in input. How I can get console.log list of names as string without use if-else? I can use only lodash lib.

Comment: did you consider calling `toString()` ?

Comment: @webNeat, the task was - to do exactly with `lodash`. I do not see the need for it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers! I have done so:

```
function printNames(names) {

    console.log(_.toString(names)); 

}; 

printNames([1,2,3]); 

printNames('1,2,3');
```

It was easier than I thought

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why there is a need for lodash for something like this, but perhaps this might fit your needs:

```js
function consoleLogList(input) {

  _.each(_.concat([], input), function (name) {

    console.log(name)

  })
}

consoleLogList('Single') // string
consoleLogList(['John', 'Mike', 'Bill']) // or array
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: @GennadiyBalachkov You're welcome :)
Please consider marking this answer as correct (by clicking on the grey checkmark on the top left of my post) if you felt that it addressed your needs. Alternatively, you could mark your own answer as correct and just upvote (by clicking on the dark grey up arrow on the top left of my post) this answer if you felt it was still useful.